# Writing a mutating function with multiple arguments in Julia

Tags: julia

I am trying to write a mutating function where the value passed as first argument mutates depending on the second one.

As an example, `remove_when_zero_in_b` below should return the values in vector `a` for those indexes where vector `b` is not `0`.

```
"""filters 'a' when there is a zero in 'b'"""
function remove_when_zero_in_b!(a::AbstractVector, b::Vector{<:Real})
    a = a[b .!= 0]
    a
end
```

E.g.

```
x = [1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0]
y = [0,   1,   0,   2  , 0 ]

remove_when_zero_in_b!(x, y) # should mutate x
```

Then `x` should be:

```
println(x)
2-element Vector{Float64}:
 2.0
 4.0
```

However, the function above does not mutate `x` and remains as the initial vector with `5` elements.

What am I missing here? How would a function mutating `x` so I obtain the desired result look like?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Mutating function in Julia (function that modifies its arguments)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39293082/mutating-function-in-julia-function-that-modifies-its-arguments)

Comment: I've marked this as a duplicate of the question @Shayan linked to, as it has an answer and a good explanation. One other method that that answer doesn't  mention is `a .= a[b .!= 0]`, which would come useful when the array is multidimensional (i.e. not just a vector).

Comment: @SundarR Are you sure about `a .= a[b .!= 0]`? didn't work either. I replaced it with `a = a[b .!= 0]` and after executing function on `x` , `y`; `x` is still the same.

Comment: @JosepEspasa probably the function you are looking for is `filter!`.

Comment: @Shayan Yeah, I should have realized that it wouldn't work in this case - it only works when the array size doesn't change. For eg. it works with `a .= a.^2`.

Comment: @SundarR Exacto!

Comment: Also, [These](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35235597/julia-function-argument-by-reference), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65723373/why-wont-this-softmax-function-i-have-written-in-julia-change-the-input-data?rq=1) can help understand the material.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`a = a[b .!= 0]` create a new copy of `a`, you can write,

```
function remove_when_zero_in_b!(a::AbstractVector, b::Vector{<:Real})
    deleteat!(a, b .== 0)
    a
end
```